# iPhone: Apple push notification issue on production server

Tags: iphone, push-notification, production-environment

I have created development and production certificates with Push Notification enabled. Everything works fine on test environment but when I try to test the development certificate on our production environment, it continuously give me following error message. Please note that the same thing works fine in test environment. Could anyone please have some idea what could be going wrong?

No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xxxx

Thanks.

Comment: Got this sorted...the firewall setting weren't enable at domain level for port 2195 but at intranet level. Hence it was working for test environment but wasn't for production!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: moving my comment here in answer section!

Got this sorted...the firewall setting weren't enable at domain level for port 2195 but at intranet level. Hence it was working for test environment but wasn't for production!